# How to install OQGRAPH plugin?

Tags: mariadb, oqgraph

I have installed MariaDB on my windows7 machine .
So how to install OQGRAPH storage engine?

I have tried following SQL query:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> INSTALL PLUGIN oqgraph SONAME 'ha_oqgraph.dll';
```

and it returns following error.

> ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library 'C:\Programmi\MariaDB 10.0\lib\plugin\ha_oqgraph.dll

Comment: Where did "Programmi" come from?

Answer (score 0):

you should consider that for installing oqgraph engine you need to install some requirements like libjudy and Boost and you should consider the version you install. ( MariaDB starting with 10.0.11 and OQGraph v3)
the Boost library >= 1.55 and Judy 1.0.5. Probably other recent versions of Boost, Judy or MSVC may work but these combinations have not been tested.

For Boost 1.55:*www.boost.org*  .
Source package for Judy 1.05:*http://judy.sourceforge.net/*  .
Follow the documented instructions for building under Windows from the command line: *https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/Building_MariaDB_on_Windows/*  .
Ensure that the following variable is set to CMAKE: **JUDY_ROOT=path\to\judy\unzipped**  .
See also comments in: **storage/oqgraph/cmake/FindJudy.cmake**   .

REGARDS